# How to use row id in controller in ap.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I am using Asp.Net MVC4 and mongoDB connection. This is my controller :

```
         public ActionResult Delete(string id)
         {
            var query = from n in ObjectMongoCollection.AsQueryable<User>()

                        where n.UserId.ToString() == id
                        select n;

            User user = query.FirstOrDefault();
            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Status = "0";  
            }
            else
            {
                ObjectMongoCollection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id".ToString(), id));
                ViewBag.Status = "1";         
            }
            return View();
```

And I want to pass this id parameter as the id of selected row of this table :

```
                 @foreach (User usr in records)
                    {
                        <tr id="@usr.UserId">

                            <td>
                                @usr.Name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @usr.Surname
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @usr.Number
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }    
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="add_delete_toolbar" />
              <button id="delete"> Delete</button>
```

How can I fill this jquery function according to my need:

```
          $('button#delete').click(function () {
             ...
          });
```

Checking which row is selecting :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#result').DataTable();

    $('#result tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is the `#delete` button in your view?

Comment: Just after the table, I added it now

Comment: How are you going to determine which row users want to delete? Are users selecting a row somehow and then pressing "delete"?

Comment: Yes I am using data table and I added new code block which helps to understand which  row is selected

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DataTable has a plugin called "TableTools" which provides many useful functionalities (including multi-select) and I suggest you to have a look. But to answer your question, try this in you code:

```
$('button#delete').click(function () {
    $("#result tbody tr.selected").each(function() {
         $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url: "ToYourController/Delete/" + this.id
         })
         .success(function() {
            alert("succeed!")
         })
         .error(function() {
            alert("failed!");
         })
    })
}
```